# Word: How do I find all locked fields in a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

is it possible to get a list of all the fields I used in a word document? I want to find out which field is locked without going through each field separately. Something similar to the the list when you show all linked files lie the one you can access for example in the menu: File -> Information -> Edit linked files.

Usually I use VBA code to go through locked fields (like this example: https://word.tips.net/T001367_Locating_Locked_Fields.html) but in this case I need to do it without the help of VBA.

Maybe there's an option I haven't found yet like marking all locked fields red, that would work as well (although I would prefer a list).

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA you are not going to find a feature that creates a list of fields in the document. What you can do from the Home tab choose the GoTo item from the Edit group and select Fields. You can then cycle thru the document fields pretty quickly.

Comment: yeah, thanks, didn't know the "GoTo"-Way yet. You can use the keyboard shortcut or the buttons under the vertikal scrollbar (don't know their name) to cycle through them as well. But this also gives me the unlocked fields. Is there a way to see if the field is locked or unlocked (without changing the locked/unlocked status)?

Answer (score 0):

With VBA you can add a comment on each locked field in the document. That gets you closer to the original list you wanted.

```
Sub FindLockedFields()
Dim rng As Word.Range
ActiveDocument.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
For Each rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Text = "^d"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            If rng.Fields.Locked = True Then
                rng.Comments.Add rng, "Locked"
            End If
            rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
Next
ActiveDocument.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
```

End Sub

Hope this helps

Comment: nice idea, but I already have VBA-Code to go through all the locked fields. Adding a comment or marking it in some other way isn't really much of a difference - just one line of code more or less. But as I stated in my question I need a solution without VBA. It would be only interesting to see if a field is locked or unlocked (without using VBA code, or changing the locked/unlocked state) as I already commented on your other answer.